# How do I normalise severely right-skewed data?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization, logarithm

I have a few continuous variables in my dataset that are severely right-skewed. I have tried several log transformations, incrementally increasing it to log(10^8). Nothing has worked. The log transformed data are still just as severely skewed as the original data. What is the best way to normalise these data? I am using SPSS 27.

EDIT: In summary, they are predictors for regression analyses.

The longer explanation... I am using these variables as predictors for both a moderation regression and a Poisson regression. For both of these analyses, some data points in my DVs are missing (it's a longitudinal dataset). I've decided to impute the missing DV datapoints using multiple imputation. Since MI is also a regression, I also need these predictor variables to be normalised in order to conduct the MI.

EDIT: Here are the scatterplot matrices with histograms of the variables before (Fig 1) and after (Fig 2) log10 transformation. As you can see, the log10 transformations were effective in normalising some of the variables, but not others. Note: Any variables with values of 0 were adjusted (+1) and left-skewed data were reciprocated before applying the transformations.

[image: Untransformed original predictor variables]

[image: Log10 transformed predictor variables]

Comment: What are you using these variables for? It might not really matter that the data are skewed.

Comment: @jcken I've added some more details to the description. I hope they provide some more clarity!

Comment: What’s the range of the variable? You mentioned trying log so is it always greater than zero?

Comment: Increasing the base of the logarithm doesn't change the degree to which the transformation reduces the skew.  It just changes the units of the outputted values.

Comment: I doubt that logarithmic transformation has no effect on right skewness, which is what you seem to be claiming.  Note that the base of logarithms you use has no effect on skewness. The skewness of (e.g.) natural logarithms, logarithms  base 10, logarithms base 2 is exactly the same, as logs to any base are just multiples of those of any other.  Normal distribution of any predictor is not a regression requirement; otherwise using (0, 1) indicators as predictors would be utterly out of order, but even so using logged predictors is often a good idea e.g. to dampen outliers and for other reasons.

Comment: If you tabulate minimum, median and quartiles and maximum then the effect of logarithms can be explored. Even better show more of the data or some histograms.

Comment: Could you post a histogram of the data? That could help with some ideas.

Comment: If you really need it to be normal, you can hit it with an empirical probability integral transform (`ecdf` in `R`) to make it $U(0,1)$, then use the uniform values as quantiles of a normal distribution to which your transformed values correspond (`qnorm` in `R`). The whole process in `R` is `ex <- ecdf(x)(x); tx <- qnorm(ex)`. There should be equivalent functions in your software of choice.

Comment: @Dave The drawback of that advice is the OP describes indications of a spike in frequency on one value (I am guessing, but this is a common problem), where *no* transformation exists that will make the data approximately Normal.  That's one (of many) reasons we need more detailed information.

Comment: We can't help more here without knowing more about the data, I suspect.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @NickCox and all. I've added the histograms of both the untransformed and transformed data.

Comment: Thanks for the graphs, but unfortunately they are pretty hard to read. So, clearly the statement "Nothing has worked" is incorrect. Where does the idea for treating left-skewed distributions  come from?

Comment: @NickCox I'll try and add some larger graphs now. I've been following suggested steps for data cleaning according to Tabachnick & Fidell (2013).

Comment: @NickCox I took the inverse of left-skewed data as log transformations are effective for right-skewed data only (as per my understanding).

Comment: Inverse means reciprocal to me in this context, whereas your wording in the question sounds like $\log (U - x)$ for $0 < x < U$.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the correction. I did mean to say reciprocal (looks like I need another cup of coffee). I've selected a few variables and made the graphs larger.

Comment: Sorry, evidently my point was unclear. I don't have a copy of this book, but from other references on the net the authors are recommending something like my formula, which as you said first is based on reflection; it is not a case of taking an  inverse or reciprocal. More important than what you call it: a quick search indicates that most of the enthusiasm for this transformation can be traced to these authors. For a left-skewed doubly bounded variable e.g. one that is $0 < x < 1$ or equivalent, logit would be more widely used, I think.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for this! I'll look into it and report back with any further questions. Really appreciate it!